# Update text on ASPX page periodically from long running background task

Tags: asp.net, multithreading, events, sharepoint, background-process

I have a an ASPX page (well, SharePoint, but it is a page on it, .net 4.5).

From this page I want to start a long running import process (lets say 15 minutes) by clicking a button. The page has a label with return information from the import process and everything is inside an update panel. The update panel works already for other stuff on the page - partial content of page (the label) gets updated dynamically.

There are many steps involved in the import (lets say, importing "departments", "users", "addresses").

What I got working is the page, starting the import process, but after some minutes it will timeout. So I don't see the progress or receive the return information of the import.

Them I thought I was clever in creating an event in my importer class and firing it after each import step with some string containing the progress information (e.g. "Imported users", "Imported addresses"). On the ASPX page I registered an event handler for this event that will update the label with the progress information (as mentioned: dynamically, as it is in an update panel).

For this to work I of course have to start the import process as non-blocking, so I guess in a separate thread, not in the UI thread of the page.

I tried to get it working using an ASYNC task and later using a simple ThreadStart(...). Problem is, I only receive some of the progress information (like the first 3). Other return information is not returned, although it looks like the import process has finished those steps.

So, now I'm questioning if this whole construct really can work (using events and a Thread or Async Task, apparently it looks like it does not work completely). Maybe there are some issues I'm not aware of when using threads on a ASPX page?

Comment: This is the sort of thing [SignalR](https://www.asp.net/signalr) is meant for. I'd ditch that UpdatePanel ASAP. They're a poor leaky abstraction. As for your long running task, you need to take care of implementing that. [Scott Hanselman](https://www.hanselman.com/blog/HowToRunBackgroundTasksInASPNET.aspx) describes some of the pitfalls. He tries to steer your towards Hangfire running in a web application. But I'd avoid that too: run your background jobs in a console application (a Windows service, perhaps with TopShelf).

Comment: OK, as I didn't have time to change the code to implement SignalR and as this behaviour was rather "nice to have" than required; I simplified my ASPX page logic and am not periodically updating it. I start the long background task in a separate thread and inform the user that I have done this. That's it :-)

Comment: You should really not start it in a separate thread. Did you read the link from Scott Hanselman I gave you?

Comment: Yeah, the threading out is only done for some manual job start for emergencies. Normally it runs in a SharePoint timerjob in the background. From my tests there were not any issues with this kind of implementation - but I know, of course something could stop the app pool but for this scenario it is not an issue.